# Access file from nested directory under PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror, pythonpath

I have checked many SO questions, but didn't help me to solve my issue. 
I have a folder structure:

```
|--test/foo.py
|--library/   #This is set as my PYTHONPATH
|--|--file1.py
|--|--folder1
|--|--|--util.py
```

I am trying to access `util.py` from `foo.py`.

Note: At this point i am able to access all the files under library from test folder. But whenever i try to access library/folder1/util.py, it gives an error saying `"ImportError: No module named util"`

I have tried this so far:
foo.py

```
 import os
 import sys
 import file1
 sys.path.insert(0, '/folder1/')
 import util
 util.function_name
 #do something
```

This approach works but then i am not able to use "library/file1.py".
Is there any cleaner way to avoid this?

Note: These are only folder structure (I am maintaining to differentiate files), not modules, (so i believe i can not use `__init__.py` and something like import `utils.functionname`)

Comment: Why don't you want library to be a package? I would argue that if it shouldn't be a package, then `folder1` should be sitting sibling to `library`. Otherewise, if it _truly_ is a library, then `library` and `folder1` should have an `__init__.py` allowing you to add `library` to the PYTHONPATH and then simply import: `library.folder1.util.functionname`

Comment: @OozeMeister - I tried the way you explained. So now i have __init__.py under library, folder1. But still i am not able to use the function i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to brute force it, run this from your top-level directory (in your case, the unnamed directory that contains `test/` and `library/`):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(myarray=($(find "$(pwd -P)" -type d)) \
  && printf '%s\n' "$(IFS=:; printf '%s' "${myarray[*]}")")
```

This will add your top-level directory and every subdirectory to the python path. No more nonsense.